# Tag [weight] ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I just checked some tags and found [weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight) to be pretty popular but yet very ambiguous.

It is used in the context of (and in most cases combined with):
[weight-gain](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-gain)
[weight-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss)
[bodyweight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bodyweight)
[weights](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weights) (or [resistance](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resistance))

I propose to retag all questions tagged with [weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight) with one or more of the more specific and appropriate tags above and burninate weight afterwards.

Comment: I'd volunteer to do the retagging if we have consensus, the burnination would have to be done from higher up.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to change everything to?

Comment: I only want to change [weight], and then either delete it or change it to one of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think retagging everything that's using [weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight) is fine. Obviously, since it's ambiguous in usage, we can't do it automagically.

I'd say we probably need to point the actual [weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight) at [body-weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body-weight), as that's the context in which it seems to be used most.

Comment: Done with the retagging. By the way, I misspelled the tag, it is actually [tag:bodyweight]. Would be great if you could put in the synonym, as I lack the reputation to vote on it.